# Linking OpenGL framework on OSX

Tags: c++, c, macos, opengl, graphics

I have a mac running Yosemite with OpenGL 4.x support, however whenever I compile c++ projects with the "-lSDL2 -framework OpenGL" flags it automatically uses OpenGL 1.20, installed under /System/Library/Frameworks. The correct version is installed in the long path within /Applications/XCode.app/...
Is there a way to make the gcc compiler correctly choose the OpenGL 4.x version over the legacy version?

EDIT:
It seems that it may not matter which is linked, it is still using the incorrect version. It does seem to use the correct version when the line "SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);" is added. However it still says that GLSL version #130 is not supported. So this may not be the problem.

Comment: Following the advice from
http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/specifying-framework-search-path-in-makefile.896608/
I found that adding -F"path" -framework OpenGL added the apparently correct path, however it still loads the older version of OpenGL despite my code requesting the newer version:
"SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);"

Comment: Output:
=== OpenGL Implementation ===
Vendor: Intel Inc.
GL Version: 4.1 INTEL-10.6.20
GL Version (Strict): 4.1
GLSL Version: 4.10
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
ERROR: 0:2: '' :  #version required and missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-isysroot` option to clang to specify a specific SDK location. For example:

```
clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk ...
```

This will tell the compiler to use all headers, libraries, etc., from this specific SDK version.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is late but it may help the others,

> SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

this line is only specify which profile is in the use, and you should be explicit with OpenGL by determine the Major and Minor Version as the two next lines.

> SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3); // determine your Maj version
> SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2); // determine your Min version

also in GLSL use :

> #version 320 core // use your version instead of 320 by putting Major Minor 0

and if you are using GLFW add also this line if you are in MAC:

> glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);